# Does it matter if i start a qt base as QMainWindow or as a QDialog?

Tags: qt

if i need multiple dialogs for my application. QmainWindow is just for layout of multiple dialogs?

Answer (score 3):

[QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html) is still a single window but it provides facilities for advanced GUI programming.

If you need to pop up multiple dialogs first read [Modeless Dialogs section](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html) of qt docs.

If basically says that create your dialogs on the heap and use show() method.

Something like below (untested code). This should show two dialogs at the same time.

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
 QApplication app;

 Mydialog1 dlg1 = new Mydialog1();
 dlg1->show ();

 Mydialog1 dlg2 = new Mydialog2();
 dlg2->show ();

 a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a QMainWindow provides a the base window for a regular GUI application. A regular GUI application is thought of as having "Menus", "Toolbars", "Status bar"
AFAIK, a QDialog does not provide any of the above. if your application doesn't require any menus, toolbars etc... then you can simply use QDialogs as you said. But I'd strongly recommend using a QMainWindow if your application has multiple widgets. If you can explain what you are trying to achieve then maybe we can help you with better alternatives.